# JSXGraph : How to create sliders outside of the box

Tags: sliders, jsxgraph

I am using the JSXGraph library for an application. I know how to use the default sliders that come with the library. However, what I'd like to know is how to use my own sliders that I created and that lie outside of the board to be linked to the graph.

thanks,

Omar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this question, it was answered in this jsxgraph google group topic https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsxgraph/VlUqPYB5Fy4